# If prop.test is an approximation to binom.test, why don't we use binom.test when computers can do it?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, proportion

When computing by hand, it makes a lot of sense to approximate the binomial distribution with a normal distribution because otherwise it would be impossible to perform calculations.

However, when using a computer to do hypothesis tests on a proportion, we keep using prop.test, which is based on the normal or the chi-squared distribution, which are approximations, instead of using binom.test that would give an exact result using the binomial distribution.

Then the question is why do we keep using prop.test instead of binom.test?

I can come with reasons to think that it doesn't matter much which one we use:

- Results are very similar for mid to large samples.
- When samples aren't large and results are (slightly) different, the power of both tests is too small to reach useful conclusions. Therefore, in real life, when doing inference on proportions samples are always large enough for both tests to be equivalent.

However, I can't come with a reason to prefer prop.test over binom.test when both are available and equally easy in a computer. Am I missing some reason? Or am I wrongly assuming than prop.test is routinely used when binom.test could be used?

Comment: I used R names prop.test an binom.test to keep the question short and clear - clearer than my limited plain English. I hope all non R users will understand.

Comment: "Or am I wrongly assuming than prop.test is routinely used when binom.test could be used?" That may well be. I wouldn't use prop.test where binom.test can be used. See my answer.

Comment: "When computing by hand, it makes a lot of sense to approximate the binomial distribution with a normal distribution because otherwise it would be impossible to perform calculations." --- not impossible, it's pretty straightforward, but potentially tedious if n is large. Impractical in many cases, perhaps.

Comment: @Glen_b - Well, I wouldn't ask my students to compute by hand P(X>500) for a B(2020, 0.25) in a test. Basically, the binomial is only manageable by hand for selected values of x and n, which fortunately match quite well the conditions when it can't be approximated with the normal or the Poisson distribution.

Comment: Neither would I; what is *possible* is not the same as "what is pedagogically useful".

Answer (score 1):

`prop.test` is for comparing two proportions in two samples. `binom.test` is for testing a hypothesis about a proportion in a single sample.

Re-reading the help page of `prop.test`, I realise that it can also be used for a one-sample test, however I don't see why anyone would do that, given that (a) `binom.test` is precise and (b) `prop.test` doesn't advertise itself as method of choice to do this in the first place.

Comment: prop.test in R can be used both for testing a proportion in a single sample and for comparing two proportions in two samples. In fact, they are the same tho tests that we do in basic statistics courses by hand using the normal distribution.

Comment: However, do you mean that that is what the test can do, or that that is what you do, or that that is what is usually done? I think your answer is less clear than your comment.

Comment: The description on the ```prop.test``` help page says "prop.test can be used for testing the null that the proportions (probabilities of success) in several groups are the same, or that they equal certain given values." I don't know whether it can be used for testing a hypothesis in a single sample, but why would anyone do that if this is not what the help page suggests? Surely I use binom.test for this, and I'd guess the vast majority does, but I haven't done a survey.

Comment: Sorry I misread that, you're right. It may be used for a single group. However I still wonder why anyone would do that, or whom you mean when you say "we"?

Comment: I mainly mean all statistics courses using R I've seen around me, which may be or not be very different from a representative sample of what happens around the world, and may also be influenced by desire to do with R the same operation that students perform by hand - which is reasonable in the teaching context.

Comment: Additionally, a Google search (for "proportion test single sample R") yields mixed results, with some pages giving both functions and some of them giving only prop.test.

Comment: I've always seen binom.test, however as I said, I haven't done a survey. I basically agree with you that binom.test should be used. A reason to use prop.test would be in an environment where both single sample and more samples can happen and need to be processed with the same command. I find it quite clear from the help page of prop.test that it's raison d'etre is two and more sample problems.